# What is the point of TRY CATCH block when XACT_ABORT is turned ON?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transaction

Code sample with XACT_ABORT_ON:

```
SET XACT_ABORT_ON;

BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    //do multiple lines of sql here
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK;
  //may be print/log/throw error
END CATCH
```

Since XACT ABORT is ON, any error will automatically rollback the transaction. So what purpose does the TRY CATCH block serve?

Comment: does this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1150350/1421050)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are right that it is not necessary to catch errors you are not intending on handling. `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` ensures a rollback in all circumstances (except for a couple of very weird edge cases of uncatchable errors, which [Erland Sommarskog says are basically unfixed bugs](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#uncatchable)). Syntax errors from dynamic SQL are also not caught and rolled back, however that is just one more good reason to use a good IDE, proper version control and avoid dynamic SQL.

In my opinion, it is only necessary to `CATCH` errors if you intend on dealing with them. Erland's articles are generally misunderstood, they are intended for *handling* errors, not just catching and re-throwing.
`SET XACT_ABORT ON;` is **always necessary**, in order to correctly roll back transactions.

And in triggers, you must *never* explicitly roll back. If you do, you will get a spurious error # 3609 `The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.` And `XACT_ABORT` is `ON` by default in triggers.

---

But there are sometimes circumstances when you do actually want to catch and handle errors within your SQL code. For this you must use `BEGIN TRY` `BEGIN CATCH`, and you also must use a conditional `ROLLBACK` as shown.

For example, you can see [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12bf2ce747394da1a15bd632759fae3c) that a second insert outside of the transaction is still committed, even though `XACT_ABORT` was `ON`, because `BEGIN CATCH` was used.

---

**TL;DR;**
You only need to use `BEGIN CATCH` and conditional `ROLLBACK;` if handling the error.
`SET XACT_ABORT` must **always** be `ON` if you have an explicit transaction, irrespective of whether there is a `CATCH`, to ensure that rollback happens correctly.

Comment: What about the opposite? i.e. are there any times when you would want `XACT_ABORT OFF`?

Comment: Yes if you specifically want statement-aborting errors to fall through. But explicit `BEGIN CATCH` blocks would make more sense there, and in any case is a bit unusual.

Answer (score 4):

The two options serve different purposes. While it's common to issue rollback within a CATCH block, this is not the only thing you can use it for. For example...

- Maybe you want to log the errors to disk or the Event log.
- Maybe you want to call a another procedure if the TRY block fails.
- Or maybe you want to send an email.

The point is the CATCH block is not limited to just rolling back a transaction. It's an entire code block on its own.

XACT_ABORT is geared more towards ensuring a block of code exits on the first error and everything is rolled back. Traditionally in SQL Server, if you do not use XACT_ABORT, it's possible for statement 1 to fail and be rolled back, while all remaining statements continue to be executed and committed. This can produced unexpected results. It's important to note that if you're enabling XACT_ABORT, be sure to use THROW instead of RAISERROR, as RAISERROR does not honor XACT_ABORT.

If you're looking for a more in-depth understanding of how TRANSACTIONS, XACT_ABORT and TRY/CATCH all work, Brent Ozar recently did a 4 part blog series on this topic.

1. [Tryin Try/Catch](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/01/error-handling-quiz-week-tryin-try-catch/)
2. [Will a Transaction Help?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/01/error-handling-quiz-week-will-a-transaction-help/)
3. [Combining Transactions and TRY/CATCH](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/01/error-handling-quiz-week-combining-transactions-and-try-catch/)
4. [Making a Turkey Sandwich with XACT_ABORT](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/01/error-handling-quiz-week-making-a-turkey-sandwich-with-xact_abort/)

Comment: Excellent series of articles, thanks.  Also see Remus Rusanu's answer to a Stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490088/216440 .  He checks XACT_STATE() to determine whether to rollback a transaction or not.

Answer (score -6):

Reading trough [this great article](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern) by Erland Sommarskog it is my understanding, that the TRANSACTION opened by your piece of code is rolled back but none of the TRANSACTIONs that may be were opened by the `//do multiple lines of sql here` or even TRANSACTIONs that were opened by code *that* code called

Comment: That's provably not true, `SET XACT_ABORT ON` will everything back https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90a5dac46965c83af4dbc8c433cd0ba8. Nested transactions are a myth, SQL Server does not support them

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for clearing that up. I am sure I can remember that now.